# "Object doesnt support this action" error in excel vba for chart.setSourceData

Tags: excel, vba

I've been encountering this error when I use the chart.setSourceData method in my function for creating a treemap chart. I can successfully setup the chart via setting it's fullseriescollection.values and fullseriescollection.xvalues properties, however for some reason this method doesn't cause the blocks in the graph to group as expected.

Below is my addchart function code

```
Function AddChart()
    dim cws as worksheet 'worksheet the chart is located on
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim ch_shape As Shape
    Dim src_rng As Range
    
    If ShapeExists("Unconverted Quotes", cws) = True Then
        Set ch_shape = cws.Shapes("Unconverted Quotes")
        Set ch = ch_shape.Chart
    Else
        cws.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlTreemap).Name = "Unconverted Quotes"
        Set ch_shape = cws.Shapes("Unconverted Quotes")
        Set ch = ch_shape.Chart
        
        ch_shape.IncrementLeft -266.25
        ch_shape.IncrementTop -32.25
        ch_shape.ScaleWidth 2.4583333333, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        ch_shape.ScaleHeight 1.3645833333, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
    End If
    
    
    If SeriesExist("UnconvertedQuotes", ch.SeriesCollection) = False Then
        ClearSeries ch.SeriesCollection
        If ch.SeriesCollection.Count < 1 Then
            ch.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.Name = "UnconvertedQuotes"
        End If
        ch.SeriesCollection(ch.SeriesCollection.Count).Name = "UnconvertedQuotes"
        
    End If
    
    
    ch.ChartStyle = 414
    ch.ApplyLayout (2)
    Set src_rng = Application.Union(Range("'Processed Report'!$B$3:$C$297"), Range("'Processed Report'!$M$3:$M$297"))
    
    ch.ChartTitle.text = "Unconverted Rates - " & cws.Range("B1")
    ch.SetSourceData Source:=src_rng
    ch.ApplyLayout (2)

End Function
```

I expected that the line `ch.SetSourceData Source:=src_rng` would function normally, however I've been receiving the error detailed in the title despite SetSourceData being a method for charts and ch being a chart. Could someone please aid me in determining why this error is being generated? I'd been suspecting that there may be some incompatibility with the treemap chart type and the SetSourceData function, but I don't really know.

Comment: Does it work without doing the `Union`? I think the range you give it has to be contiguous.

Comment: @braX Unfortunately it doesn't. I've recently done a bit more testing and it works fine with pie and bar charts, so it really may be due to some incompatibility with treemaps.